# Debugging Cucumber test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, simple-form

I have a page that appears to work, but my cucumber test is giving errors.

The relevant bits of the page in HAML:

```
= simple_form_for(@client, url: { action: "update_password" }, html: { method: :put }) do |f|
  STUFF
  = f.submit "Update password", id: "submit", :class => "btn btn-primary submit"
```

The line that's crashing is "And I submit the form" which is:

```
When /^I submit the form$/ do
  generic_form_page = GenericFormPage.new(Capybara.current_session)
  generic_form_page.submit

  if Capybara.current_session.mode == :poltergeist
    ajax_page = GenericAjaxPage.new Capybara.current_session
    ajax_page.wait_for_ajax_call_to_finish
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

```
And I submit the form    # features/step_definitions/shared/common_steps.rb:30
  Unable to find css ".simple_form input[type=submit]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/pages/support/form_page_mixin.rb:3:in `submit'
  ./features/step_definitions/shared/common_steps.rb:32:in `/^I submit the form$/'
  features/admin/change_client_password.feature:22:in `And I submit the form'
```

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward -- there is no visible element on the page matching the reported CSS selector -  Use `save_and_open_screenshot` or `save_and_open_page` to see what's actually on the page, odds are you're not actually on the page you think you are.

Comment: You are correct. I'll create a new question to figure out WHY I'm not on the page I expect to be on.